# docker run does absolutely nothing, no log created

Tags: docker

I am attempting to run the following docker container:
https://hub.docker.com/r/bgruening/pubmedportable/

I am doing so using the following command:
`sudo docker run -d -v /home/$USER/docker_pubmedportable/:/export/ -p 9999:5432 bgruening/pubmedportable`

The only output I get is immediately returned:
`9b76caddaddbe262bf30d3edbab30da9fa29b9e5f1ad3a4148e753f4e5e929bd`

And that is all that is done. There should be a postgres server that is instantiated/created, filled with data, and then hosted at the port 9999 on localhost.

I tried looking at the logs via:
`docker logs -f 9b76caddaddbe262bf30d3edbab30da9fa29b9e5f1ad3a4148e753f4e5e929bd`

However, this also returns no information.

Also, running `docker ps` provides absolutely nothing after the commands are issued.

It is my understanding that docker containers are supposed to "just work" on any platform, with little to no effort required.

However, this docker container has not been able to create and host this database and does not appear to be running at all.

Is there a method to determine which section of the docker container is causing a problem?

The OS is archlinux.

Comment: please mention what is the os an docker details. I tried in ubuntu it's printing logs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some error is making the container exits.
Run it without the -d option, so you can see the log.

Comment: running it without `-d` gives a blank newline and that's it

Comment: Run the command `docker ps -a`, remove using `docker rm {container_id}` any container instance your system has and try running it again.

Comment: I removed all docker containers with `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)` and tried running the `docker run` statement again, without `-d`. It still yeilds no output

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bring up the container with your command. I adapted the path to my environment.

```
..[$] <()> docker run -d -v ${pwd}:/export/ -p 9999:5432 bgruening/pubmedportable
1d21b00a5fdd376016bb09aeb472a295b86f74aea385a609ca8b33a0ba87f306
..[$] <()> docker logs 1d21b00a5fdd376016bb09aeb472a295b86f74aea385a609ca8b33a0ba87f306
Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server: main.
Initialized with  4 processes
######################
###### Finished ######
######################
programme started - Sat Sep 15 04:47:35 2018
programme ended - Sat Sep 15 04:47:36 2018
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:3779: SAWarning: Textual SQL expression '\n            SELECT \n    ...' should be explicitly declared as text('\n            SELECT \n    ...') (this warning may be suppressed after 10 occurrences)
  {"expr": util.ellipses_string(element)})

-------------
processing files from year 1809 to 2016
-------------
got articles from PostgreSQL database
-------------
now indexing articles in Xapian

-------------
no search of synonyms performed, use "python RunXapian.py -h" for parameter view
2017-06-01 00:50:17 UTC LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2017-06-01 00:50:17 UTC LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2017-06-01 00:50:17 UTC LOG:  shutting down
2017-06-01 00:50:17 UTC LOG:  database system is shut down
2018-09-15 04:47:34 UTC LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-06-01 00:50:17 UTC
2018-09-15 04:47:34 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2018-09-15 04:47:34 UTC LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2018-09-15 04:47:34 UTC LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2018-09-15 04:47:36 UTC LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2018-09-15 04:47:36 UTC LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection

..[$] <()> psql -h localhost -p 9999 -U parser pubmed
Password for user parser:
psql (10.5, server 9.1.24)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: on)
Type "help" for help.

pubmed=#
```